# Can a condition in a loop be used without an initializer?

Tags: javascript, loops, initializer

As a condition in *for* or *while* loops, can you use a statement without "i"?

For example:

```
for (let i = 0 ; myArray.length =< 7; i++)
```

I want the loop to run until my condition is met, but not sure if I can achieve that without including the "i" there.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ( initiaizer; condition; increment) {
    body
}
```

is the same as:

```
initializer 
while (condition) {
    body
    increment
}
```

And you can follow the same rules in each. Meaning initializer and increment are actually optional (`for (; false; ) {}` is valid). Creating and incrementing a variable called `i` is just a useful convention and has no special meaning.

For loops were invented to simplify while loops in the common case where you want to basically count from one number to another. If you’re not doing that, a while loop might be better.

Comment: `for(;;){ break }` - the condition is optional too, it would just require manually breaking out of the loop.

Comment: didn’t realise that, nice!

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! No resource I consulted mentioned it or included an example without the i variable.

Comment: For loops are a bit bizarre and the way they’re structured only really makes sense in reference to while loops (semicolons inside the `()`???). I prefer array methods most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
while (myArray.length <= 7) {

}
```

with `<=`, not `=<`

Answer (score 1):

In this condition you should use **[while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)** loop

```
while (condition)
  statement
```

But you can also use **for...of** and **forEach** and same **for** loop like below:

You can use **[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)**

```
const iterable = 'boo';

for (const value of iterable) {
  if(mycondition){
   console.log(value);
  }
}
```

**OR**

You can also use **[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**

```
const items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
const copyItems = []
items.forEach(function(item){
  if(mycondition){
   copyItems.push(item)
  }
})
```

**OR**

**[for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)**

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

`for (;;)` is an infinite loop equivalent to while (true) because there is no test condition.

`for ( ; s < myArray.length ; s++)` is a loop with no initialization. s will point to the beginning and is incremented until it end.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `condition` but no need for an `iterator`, it's customary to use a `while loop`:

```
while (myArray.length < 8) {

  [... CODE HERE ...]
}
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: Thanks! That's actually where I'm studying, however, no examples of loops without an initializer so far.